# PHP Warning: mail(): Multiple or malformed newlines found

Tags: php, header

Our host upgraded PHP on the new server and after words I started getting this error *( PHP Warning:  mail(): Multiple or malformed newlines found in additional_header in /home/ucmin34/public_html/store/secure/checkout.php on line 505)*

I know it has to do with headers but I didn't write the orginal code and just trying to figure out the quickest fix to get emails flowing after orders are placed. Any help would be great.

```
function sendHTMLemail($HTML,$plain,$from,$to,$subject)
{
$headers = "From: $from\r\n"; 
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$boundary = uniqid("HTMLEMAIL"); 
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;".
            "boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n"; 
$headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message.\r\n\r\n"; 
$headers .= "--$boundary\r\n".
            "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n".
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";                
$headers .= chunk_split(base64_encode($plain)); 
$headers .= "--$boundary\r\n".
            "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n".
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";       
$headers .= chunk_split(base64_encode($HTML)); 
return mail($to,$subject,"",$headers);
}
function prettyAddress($fname,$lname,$addr1,$addr2,$city,$state,$zip,$country)
{
$out = ucwords($fname." ".$lname)."<br>".ucwords($addr1)."<br>";
if($addr2)
    $out .= ucwords($addr2)."<br>";
$out .= ucwords($city.", ".$state." ".$zip)."<br>".$country;
return $out;  
}
?>
```

Comment: Please remove each header one by one to see which one is triggering the problem.

Comment: Maxime... i took them out one by one and still got error until i removed the line below. I am not that experienced with PHP so not sure why. 

return mail($to,$subject,"",$headers);